# Inserting multiple IP address's into database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, curl

I'm having an issue inserting multiple IP address's (proxies) **scraped** using cURL into my database in 127.0.0.1:8080 format.

I'm able to display the data within PHP using print_r($proxies), but when saving to my database I'm only able to save the first 3 values of the IP address and nothing else.

All I want to do is save the proxies in 127.0.0.1:8080 etc format within my database, but I'm only getting the first value of the IP address inserted, (1, 12, 127) etc instead of (127.0.0.1:8080).

When creating my table/columns within the database I have used.

- Table Name: socks5
- Column Name: proxies
- Type: int(20)
- Attributes: UNSIGNED

Here is my code.

scraper.php

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/lib/dblibary.class.php';
$app = new DBLib;


$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozillia/5.0');

$proxies = array();

$start_count = 1;
$end_count = 10;

for($i = $start_count; $i <= $end_count; $i++) {

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.my-proxy.com/free-proxy-list-$i.html");

    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    
    preg_match_all("!\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}:\d{2,4}!",$result,$matches);

        foreach($matches[0] as $match) { 
        
        $proxies = $app->GrabProxy($match);
    }
    
}

curl_close($curl);  
//Display the proxies within HTML(This works and displays IP & Port)
//echo '<pre>'; print_r($proxies); echo '</pre>';
```

/lib/dblibary.class.php

```
 public function GrabProxy($match) {

    try {
        $db = DB();
        $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO socks5 (proxies) VALUES (:proxies)");
        $query->bindParam("proxies", $match, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->execute();
        if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        exit($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate any help with this.
Thanks.

Comment: In your bind, you are using `PDO::PARAM_INT` - as this is only for integers it will only take the first set of digits.  Should it be `PDO::PARAM_STR` (also assuming the column is defined as a character field).

Comment: Thank you so much !, I have no idea what was going through my head. It was an easy fix!!. I did what you said, created the table/column again using VARCHAR(255), and changing bind to PDO::PARAM_STR

Comment: don't store strings as INTegers, instead store strings as strings (mysql has several string types, like MEDIUMTEXT , check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-types.html  ) also read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer 
- integers are NUMBERS, not STRINGS

Comment: first of all - what the error gives you MySQL? why you can't add more- if there is an error then show it
Second - don't run add in a loop, take all IP's into an array, make this array as unique
And general - int means that you store only digitals, but IP address is a string
if you want to store it as numbers then you have to split it by dots as 4 sets of numbers and semicolon as port

Answer (score 0):

did you try to change column type into varchar(200) instead of int ?!

Comment: I just did that before and it worked. I also changed the bind from `PDO::PARAM_INT` to `PDO::PARAM_STR` within my dblibary.class.php file.